# How many zeros does $\sin(z)-100z^9$ have with $|z|<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

I have to find out how many zeros $\sin(z)-100z^9$ has with $|z|<1$

My approach was to use Roché's Theorem in the following way:

Let $g(z) = \sin(z)-100z^9$ and $f(z) = -100z^9$

For $|z| = 1$ we get:

$|g(z)-f(z)| = |\sin(z)| = \sin(1) < 100 = |-100z^9| = |f(z)|$

I then concluded that $g(z)$ has $9$ zeros where $|z|=1$

I was wondering if this is the correct use of the Roché theorem or if I'm completely off.

Thank you so much for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You are conclusion is right but your argument has many mistakes. Look at the statement of Rouche's Theorem again . It  states that for any two complex-valued functions f and g holomorphic inside some region
${\displaystyle K}$ with closed contour ${\displaystyle \partial K}$ if $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on ${\displaystyle \partial K}$, then $f$ and $f + g$ have the same number of zeros inside ${\displaystyle K}$, where each zero is counted as many times as its multiplicity.

So by how you defined it we end up with $f+g=\sin(z)-200z^{9}$.

Also $|\sin(z)|\neq \sin(1)$ for $|z|=1$. You cannot conclude say that $f(|z|)=|f(z)|$ for some function. This is not true.

For example if I take $z=i$ then $|z|=1$ but $\displaystyle |\sin(i)|=|\frac{e^{-1}-e^{1}}{2}|>1$ . You have to keep in mind that the arguments are complex and not real . $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ is only valid for real numbers $x$. But you can in fact have $|\sin(z)|$ as large as you want.

Here's how you should do it:-

Let $f(z)=-100z^{9}$ and $g(z)=\sin(z)$

Then on $|z|=1$ ,

You have $$
    |g(z)|
    = |\sin(z)|
    = \left|\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\right|
    \leq \frac{1}{2}(|e^{iz}| + |e^{-iz}|) \\
    \leq \frac{1}{2}(|e^{i(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)}| + |e^{-i(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)}|) \\
    = \frac{1}{2}(e^{-\sin\theta} + e^{\sin\theta})
    \leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{-1} + e),
$$  where $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta,\,0\leq\theta<2\pi$ is an arbitrary point on the unit disc.

And $|f(z)|=100\,\,,\forall |z|=1$.

Now you have $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ for all $|z|=1$ which is the boundary of the disc $|z|\leq 1 $  and hence by Rouche's Theorem you have that $f+g$ have the same number of zeroes as $f$ inside the unit disc which is $9$.